# Typo3 rendering multible pages onto one using sr_include_pages extention

Tags: plugins, typo3

I'm a total newbie in typo3 and I'm creating this website for a client of mine.
What I am trying to achieve is to render multible pages onto one page. So i did a little research and stubled upon the sr_include_pages extention. According to the description the extention fits my needs perfectly, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.
This is my page-setup so far:

- six pages
- the first one has two records in it. one is plain text. the other is
  the sr_include_pages extention (both at colPos 0)
- the other five pages contain a plain text record (for the time being)
  each all at colPos 0

on the first page i added some simple typoscript as follows:

```
plugin.tx_srincludepages_pi1
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = CONTENT
page.10.table = tt_content
page.10.select{
  where = colPos = 0
}
page.10.renderObj = COA
page.10.renderObj{
  10 = TEXT
  10.field = header
  10.wrap = <h1>|</h1>
  20 = TEXT
  20.field = bodytext
  30 < plugin.tx_srincludepages_pi1
}
```

when i switch to the frontend it renders everthing (even the header i added in the plugin record) but the content from the other five pages.
If you guys know a simpler way of solving this problem im open for everything

If this is some noob question im posting here i apologize. But I realy tried to do my homework before posting.
Thanks!
spiked_mp

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hardcode the page ids, you should
be fine with (having incuded css_styled_content)

page.10 < styles.content.get
page.10.select.pidInList = 1,2,4

Not very flexible, though.
Here's a thread on this subject
http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2011-August/076460.html